# multiply and divide values with power of ten in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i divide value that has power of 10 in javascript?

For example:

```
-5x10^-3 * 3x10^-9
```

is there a way to do this like a

```
Math.powof(5,-3)
```

something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use exponent notation?

```
-5e-3 * 3e-9
```

which is equivalent to:

```
-0.005 * 0.000000003;
```

Note that when dealing with small decimals, javascript arithmatic may not be exact, e.g.

```
(-5 * Math.pow(10, -3)) * (3 * Math.pow(10,-9)) // -1.5000000000000003e-11
```

but

```
-5 * Math.pow(10, -3) * 3 * Math.pow(10,-9)  // -1.5e-11
```

Comment: Great. Only you must add comment for _(-5e-3 * 3e-9)_ that it's only for power of tens.

Comment: Why re-state what is in the OP?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
5 × Math.pow(10,-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost, Math.pow(x, y) where x is is to the power of y so include it in whatever equation you need

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`Math.pow(base,exponent)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow), which lets you take `base` to the power of `exponent`. From there you can do something like this:

```
function powOf10(num,exp) {
   return num * Math.pow(10,exp);
}

alert(powOf10(5,-3));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the examples but what ur main functionality i didn't understand but look this hope you get some

```
(Math.pow((-5*10),-3)) * (Math.pow(3*10),-9)
```

or

```
(-5 * Math.pow(10,-3)) * (3 * Math.pow(10),-9)
```

Comment: This answer has the order of operation wrong. Instead of `Math.pow((-5*10),-3)` you need `-5 * Math.pow(10,-3)`.